# Culori js works in Svelte REPL but not in local project

Tags: svelte, rollup

The Culori package works just fine in the Svelte [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/d550a8d921f84220b4fe7f1963831418?version=3.44.1) but when I run it locally I get undefined. I've tried downloading the REPL and starting a fresh project with degit and installing Culori, nothing works.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Download the zip file for https://svelte.dev/repl/d550a8d921f84220b4fe7f1963831418?version=3.44.1
2. Extract contents
3. npm install
4. npm run dev

I see this error in console:

```
[rollup-plugin-svelte] The following packages did not export their `package.json` file so we could not check the "svelte" field. If you had difficulties importing svelte components from a package, 
then please contact the author and ask them to export the package.json file.

- culori
```

The only workaround I've found is using Culori via CDN which I'd rather avoid. Is there any way to get Culori working in a local Svelte project like it works on the REPL?